# Laravel SSH - push output to an array

Tags: php, laravel-5, closures

I have the following:

```
$files = [];
$directories = [];
\SSH::run($commands, function($line)
        {
            $data = explode('-', $line.PHP_EOL);
            if ($data[0] == 'file') {
                array_push($files, $data[1]);
            } else {
                array_push($directories, $data[1]);
            }
        });
```

However I don't have access to the two arrays during the ssh command runtime, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `use` keyword to put those variables into closure this way:

```
\SSH::run($commands, function($line) use (&$files, &$directories)
```

instead of

```
\SSH::run($commands, function($line)
```

Comment: thanks, that works however now I have the issue that only the first value of `$line.PHP_EOL` is being captured, how can I edit this to run while there is still output comming through from the ssh command?